# how can i clear my regnum block if duplicate is entered with an message

Tags: javascript, java, spring

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String getTime() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    float r = rand.nextFloat() * 100;
    String result = "<br>Next Random # is <b>" + r + "</b>. Generated on <b>" + new Date().toString() + "</b>";
    System.out.println("Debug Message from CrunchifySpringAjaxJQuery Controller.." + new Date().toString());
    return result;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String processAJAXRequest(@RequestParam("regnum") String regnum, ModelMap map)
{
       /*System.out.println(regnum); 
       System.out.println(studentService.studentRegNo(regnum));*/
       boolean b=  studentService.studentRegNo(regnum);
       if(b==true)
       {
          return "Give the Different Reg number";
       }
       else
       {
          return "Enter";
       }
}
```

IN JSP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function crunchifyAjax() {
        var regnum = $('#regnum').val();    
        /* alert(regnum); */
        var data = 'regnum='
            + encodeURIComponent(regnum);

        /* alert("inside ajax"); */
        $.ajax({
            url : 'profile.html',
            data : data,
            success : function(data) {/* alert(data); */
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<td><form:label path="regnumber">Registration Number<span class="mandatory">*</span></form:label></td>
<td>
<form:input path="regnumber" class="textFLD" required="required"  onblur="crunchifyAjax();" id="regnum"/></td>
<td width="40%"><div id="result" class="message" ></div></td>
```

I had posted my controller and jsp page please help me to clear my textbox if duplicates are entered to regnum field now message is displaying when duplicates are entered but i also want to clear textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to clear the input:

```
 /* alert("inside ajax"); */
    $.ajax({
        url : 'profile.html',
        data : data,
        success : function(data) {/* alert(data); */
            if(data=='Give the Different Reg number'){
                $('#regnum').val('');
                }  
       else {
             $('#result').html(data);
            }
        }
    });
```